# Error occurs when deploying the UWP application (installedLocation != null)

Tags: windows, uwp, desktop-application, jetbrains-ide, rider

#### Introduction

The project was newly created and there was no change in the project.

The build of the application when running the application in JetBrains Rider IDE was executed.

#### Successful Build

The build completed successfully

```
0>------- Finished building project: TEST. Succeeded: True. Errors: 0. Warnings: 0
Build completed in 00:00:34.171
Build succeeded at 04:11:43
```

#### Failed Deployment

The deployment was not completed successfully.

```
Deploying file MainPage.xbf...
Deploying file WinMetadata\Windows.winmd...
Deploying file resources.pri...
Deploying file TEST.exe...

installedLocation != null
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I changed IDE from VS to Rider. The problem was that I had a project with the same name in VS and it had been previously built, but I could not have found the deployed application. So I looked up for this VS project, built it, and then I deleted the application with the VS solution together. After this, I could run my Rider project with the same name without any errors.